# Accessing environment variables using $ in Scala process

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use a command that uses environment variables, and following is working fine( this is not the actual command I'm going to use).

```
Seq("echo "+System.getenv("JAVA_HOME"))!
```

but is there way to use the following kind of syntax ? In the case if we load the command from .sh file ?

```
Seq("echo ${JAVA_HOME}")!
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **scala** process with `bash -c` to get environment variables:

```
import scala.sys.process._
val value = Seq("bash", "-c", "echo $JAVA_HOME").lines.head
```

Comment: @chengphi yes , I'm want to access environment variables as we use in standard scripts instead of using System.getenv